# msdeploy and regex replace a connection string value

Tags: powershell, msdeploy

I have a web.config with an entity framework connection string.

That is a sample of such a string:

```
<add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/GeneratedModel.MyModel.csdl|res://*/GeneratedModel.MyModel.ssdl|res://*/GeneratedModel.MyModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=CRAP;persist security info=True;user id=MyUser;password=password;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I want to replace the **initial catalog** aka **database name** "CRAP" with the new name "TEST"

That code should work as it worked before with another msdeploy.exe command.

I just had to re-structure the $msd variable...

```
$newActiveTargetDbName = 'TEST';

$msd = "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe"
$iisPath = "MyWebSite/MyService,wmsvc='MyMachine:MyPort/msdeploy.axd',userName='username',password='password'"
& $msd -verb=sync -allowUntrusted -dest=contentPath="$iisPath" -source=contentPath="$iisPath" -setParam=kind="TextFile,match=""(MyEntities.*?catalog=).*?(;)"",scope=web.config$,value=`$1$newActiveTargetDbName`$2"
```

When I run the above statement I get this connection string in the web.config:

```
 <add name="$1TEST$2persist security info=True;user id=MyUser;password=password;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

It seems to me that I need somewhere some single/double quotes etc... but I tried actually all kind of combinations and its driving me insane.

How can I fix that?

**UPDATE**

This is a syntax of the msdeploy statement how it **WORKED** before I changed it!

```
$iisServicePath = 'MyWebsite/MyService'; 
$iisPath = "$iisServicePath,computerName=%TargetComputerName%,userName=%NTUserName%,password=%NTUserPassword%"

& "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" `
"-source=contentPath=$iisPath" `
'-verb=sync' `
'-verbose' `
'-allowUntrusted' `
"-dest=contentPath=$iisPath" `
"-setParam=kind=TextFile,match=""(MyEntities.*?catalog=).*?(;)"",scope=web.config$,value=`$1$newActiveTargetDbName`$2";
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `msdeploy.exe`, but I do seem some errors ...

[According to the docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569106(v=ws.10).aspx), you should be using a colon (`:`) after the initial parameter name; such as: `-dest:contentPath` instead of `-dest=contentPath`.

Additionally (remember, these are guesses cause I'm not familiar with `msdeploy.exe`):

1. You're missing the double-quote after `TextFile`.
2. You shouldn't have double double-quotes around your `match` value.
3. I'm not sure you want the `$` after `web.config`, but I'll leave it alone since it seems to have found your file.

I think you're final line needs to looks something like this:

```
& $msd -verb=sync -allowUntrusted -dest:contentPath="$iisPath" -source:contentPath="$iisPath" -setParam:kind="TextFile",match="(MyEntities.*?catalog=).*?(;)",scope=web.config$,value="`$1$newActiveTargetDbName`$2"
```

I hope this helps!

## Update

Based on your working one, *which I doubt works since it's using `%` variable names (not how POSH does things)*, this should do what you want:

```
& $msd -verb=sync -allowUntrusted -dest=contentPath="$iisPath" -source=contentPath="$iisPath" -setParam=kind=TextFile,match="(MyEntities.*?catalog=).*?(;)",scope=web.config$,value="`$1$newActiveTargetDbName`$2"
```

**Note:** *there's also several unanswered variables; if you're giving us the full code then there's a ton of errors.*

## Update 2

After reviewing everything again (with little feedback from the OP), this is how I would do it in PowerShell. I'm not 100% sure that your arguments are correct:

```
#region Set These Variables
$computername = $env:ComputerName
$nt_username = 'username'
$nt_password = 'password'
$newActiveTargetDbName = 'newActiveTargetDbName'
#endregion

$msd = "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe"
$iisServicePath = 'MyWebsite/MyService'
$iisPath = "${iisServicePath},computerName=${computername},userName=${nt_username},password=${nt_password}"

$start_process = @{
    'FilePath' = $msd;
    'ArgumentList' = @(
        '-verb=sync',
        '-allowUntrusted',
        "-dest=contentPath=""${iisPath}""",
        "-source=contentPath=""${iisPath}""",
        "-setParam=kind=""TextFile,match='(MyEntities.*?catalog=).*?(;)',scope=web.config$,value=`$1${newActiveTargetDbName}`$2"""
    );
    'Wait' = $True
}

$process = Start-Process @start_process
```

This will give you a command that would look like this in Command Prompt:

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb=sync -allowUntrusted -dest=contentPath="MyWebsite/MyService,computerName=V-ASUSM32,userName=username,password=password" -source=contentPath="MyWebsite/MyService,computerName=V-ASUSM32,userName=username,password=password" -setParam=kind="TextFile,match='(MyEntities.*?catalog=).*?(;)',scope=web.config$,value=$1newActiveTargetDbName$2"
```

**Note:** In the `setParam` argument, I changed `match` to single quotes because it looked to me like it was going to mess up your double quotes around `kind`. If `msdeploy.exe` doesn't like single quotes, we'll need an actual working command from CMD to figure out what's going on.

Comment: I updated my question with the former working sample. There you see that -dest=contentPath is totally fine. I did like your final line suggestion and get this error: msdeploy.exe : Error: Unrecognized argument 'match=(ErpProductsEntities.*?catalog=).*?(;)'. All arguments must begin with "-".

Comment: Your multiline sample throws exceptions/errors. I know you said you are not familiar with msdeploy, but you really should try your sample in a PS IDE else people think that sample might work or be a solution :-)

Comment: @Elisabeth, Did you try the single-line example? I had a note after the multiline example: ***Note:*** *this deliberately not proper posh multi-line syntax because I don't want the back-ticks (`) to break the syntax highlighting.*

Comment: @Elisabeth, I took out the multi-line example to avoid further confusion. Also, I updated to address your update. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks I will try it tomorrow. If it would not be that crap entity framework connection string I would have used xpath with the matching but does/did not work with that kind of EF connection string...

Comment: @Elisabeth Did you fix it?

Comment: No, msdeploy is a mess!

Comment: At this point, I think you need to type the command you want in CMD and paste it back here if it works. I can make it into POSH for you if I know what the final, working command should be.

Comment: For example, I'd want something like this: `"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb=sync -allowUntrusted -dest=contentPath="MyWebSite/MyService,wmsvc='MyMachine:MyPort/msdeploy.axd',userName='username',password='password'" -source=contentPath="MyWebSite/MyService,wmsvc='MyMachine:MyPort/msdeploy.axd',userName='username',password='password'" -setParam=kind="TextFile,match=""(MyEntities.*?catalog=).*?(;)"",scope=web.config$,value=$1$newActiveTargetDbName$2"`

Comment: Added *Update 2* ... after reviewing everything again, it's the approach that I would take. I still am not sure your arguments your correct.